# Perl regular expression, seeking SKU number

Tags: regex, perl, ack

I'm trying to parse through a bunch of PHP code using [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/).  I'm pretty inexperienced with regular expressions and trying to figure out why what I'm using currently won't work as I expect.

I am trying to find all lines in PHP files that match a pattern of:

The string "SKU", followed by any amount of any character, followed by an actual SKU (sequence of numbers of indeterminate length).

My regexp is currently:

```
SKU.*[0-9]*
```

but this matches a lot of strings which don't really fit the pattern I'm seeking, such as

`SKUs</h3>` and `SKU',`

I also tried:

```
SKU(.*)([0-9]*)
```

to no avail.

Any gurus out there have some insight?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.*` means "match 0 or more of any characters"; What do the actual values you want to match look like?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to match? "Any amount of any character" is matching things like `s</h` just as you describe.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your interest, I was looking for strings such as "SKU' => 8290918290".  I realized that * represented 0 or more characters, and I was looking for +, which represents 1 or more.  Much better results.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, `SKU.*[0-9]+` will still match `SKUs</h3`. Is that what you want?

Comment: It's not exactly perfect but good enough for my purposes.

Comment: On second thought, this is even better: `SKU.*[0-9]{3,}` .  Matching at least three numbers excises all of the flotsam and jetsam that I didn't want.  Thanks again everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All (almost) right:

```
SKU.*[0-9]+
```

You must use + instead of * if you want to have at least one number at the end of re.

To say truth that is no fully clear what do you mean with *any characters*. If you really mean any character then you must use `.*`, but if not you must say more concrete what you want to find.

Also, it's possible that you will need non-greedy mode of search:

```
SKU.*?[0-9]+
```

That means: stop as soon as you face first number.

Comment: Exactly right!  Just realized this myself.  I will mark your answer as the accepted one when the time limit is up.  Thanks much.